# Limiting the rows in on table by a group based on the values in another table in Hive

Tags: hive

---

I Tried this First.

```
Create table tablec (
 id string,
 group int,
 rownumber int);

insert into table c 
select * from (select distinct a.id,a.group,a.rownumber from 
table a join table b 
on a.group = b.group where a.rownumber <= b.rownumber ) T;
```

I tried below query as well and getting same result.

```
insert into table c 
select * from (select a.id, a.group, a.rownumber from 
table a , table b 
where a.group = b.group and a.rownumber <= b.rownumber ) T;
```

I don't get an error when I run the query. It's creating table c but the values are not limited. Can anyone suggest me why its happening?

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMU1y.png)

Comment: Please ask me if there are any questions.  And thank you Jonny for editing.  I tried to post with correct format but didn't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't have to use `JOIN` and `DISTINCT` . A correlated `exists` query like this should be fine. Firstly, see if  it gives you only the desired records. Then run your `Insert` statement with this select.

```
SELECT a.group_id
    ,a.group_name
    ,a.rownumber
FROM tablea a
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tableb b
        WHERE a.group_id = b.group_id
            AND a.rownumber <= b.rownumber
        );
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82e7a3/1)